# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in login page

Tags: asp.net

I m new into ASP.net, creating a basic login page. I m getting following error when I m trying to compile:

"An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'."

Following is my code, Can anybody explain me what I m doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;



public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from Table where username = '" + username.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("Username Already Exist");
        }
        conn.Close();

    }

}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string insertQuery = "insert into Table (username, email, password) values (@username, @email, @password)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailID.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwrd.Text);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("default3.aspx");
        Response.Write("Your registration is successful");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());

    }


    Response.Write("Your form has been submitted");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table` is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL (for fairly obvious reasons).  The quick fix is to explicitly enclose the identifier:

```
  select count(*) from [Table] where ...
```

A more apt fix would be to give your tables more meaningful names.  There's a reason car companies don't name their vehicles `Car`.  It has a high potential for confusion.